# custom CSS in shiny box

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to create a `box` that contains a title on the upper left corner and a small icon on the top right. The `HTML` would look something like this:

```
<div class="box-header">
  <h3 class="box-title">TOTAL DAY</h3>
  <img class="box-title" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ab40c688a7362255373fc5f185b9698?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1">
</div>
```

With the following `css` changes:

```
.box-header .box-title{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

img{
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: right;
  height: 2vh;
}
```

The result would look something like this:

[image]

Adding the `css` is easy but is there a way to add an `<img>` like this in `shiny`?

Comment: HTML tags can be added in the `ui` function of shiny e.g. `shiny::img("photo.png")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda solved my own problem.. oops

I used this in the `box` function:

```
title = HTML("<h3 class=box-title>TOTAL DAY</h3><img class=box-title src=https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ab40c688a7362255373fc5f185b9698?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1></img>")
```

Wrapping the `HTML` in an `HTML()` function allowed `shiny` to read the `HTML` as code rather than character